# Google Chart with time from php json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, google-visualization

I have this json output from the file countrows.php:

```
[  
   {  
      "time_stamp":"08:22:46 am",
      "ph":"8",
      "moist":"0"
   },
   {  
      "time_stamp":"08:22:50 am",
      "ph":"8",
      "moist":"0"
   },
   {  
      "time_stamp":"08:22:54 am",
      "ph":"8",
      "moist":"0"
   },
   {  
      "time_stamp":"08:22:57 am",
      "ph":"8",
      "moist":"0"
   },
   {  
      "time_stamp":"08:23:01 am",
      "ph":"8",
      "moist":"0"
   },
   {  
      "time_stamp":"08:23:05 am",
      "ph":"8",
      "moist":"0"
   },
   {  
      "time_stamp":"08:23:09 am",
      "ph":"8",
      "moist":"0"
   }
]
```

The thing here is I want to show the time(coming from my json file) in my chart, specifically in the horizontal side. Something like the image below but the yellow green line shows the time from my json file.

[image]

By the way the following is my javascript code in my google chart,I need help on what to do with the following code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

// onload callback
function drawChart() {
  // JSONP request
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: 'countrows.php',
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function (results) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    data.addColumn('datetime', 'time_stamp');
    data.addColumn('number', 'ph');
    data.addColumn('number', 'moist');

    $.each(results, function (i, row) {
      data.addRow([
       new Date(row.time_stamp),
       parseFloat(row.ph),
       parseFloat(row.moist)
       ]);
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($('#chart').get(0));

    chart.draw(data, {
      title: 'Soil Analysis',
      curveType: 'function',
      displayAnnotations: true,
      //legend: { position: 'bottom' }
      pointSize: 10
      hAxis: {format: 'Y,M,d,H';}
    });
  });
}

drawChart();

setInterval(drawChart, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way would be to change the first column to --> `'string'`

```
data.addColumn('string', 'time_stamp');
```

also, since ajax is async, no need to assign to a variable,
remove this --> `var jsonData =`

and remove from argument to the data table constructor...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);  // <-- remove jsonData
```

try following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

// onload callback
function drawChart() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'countrows.php',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (results) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'time_stamp');
    data.addColumn('number', 'ph');
    data.addColumn('number', 'moist');
    $.each(results, function (i, row) {
      data.addRow([
        row.time_stamp,
        parseFloat(row.ph),
        parseFloat(row.moist)
      ]);
    });
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($('#chart').get(0));
    chart.draw(data, {
      title: 'Soil Analysis',
      curveType: 'function',
      pointSize: 10
    });
  });
}
drawChart();
setInterval(drawChart, 10000);
```

Comment: thank you so much you never failed me and always help me..thank you thank you.. ^_^